# How do I get an overlay to appear on a button click and then that button stay above the overlay in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm developing an app and I want the button I click on to activate a total screen overlay. Basically turn the screen darker whilst keeping the button I've clicked above this overlay. Ive managed to hack my way through it by putting a container with a black opacity in a stack with the button and then have it show on click but it doesn't fully over the screen because of the space the bottom navigation bar takes. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a hacky way of doing it. I put the controller.currentPage and the bottom nav bar into a stack with a container with Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5). then just triggered in on click. kinda works but its hacky.

[image]